Accessibility on ember outlet elements
I have an ember web application, with a simplified structure of landing page like this:
   <container>
       <header></header>
       <main> {{outlet}} </main>
       <footer></footer>
    </container>

I'm facing an accessibility issue.
On my main page when I navigate between clickable elements with the "tab" key,
clickable items projected in outlet are not accessible.
Also, when I manually change my focus to the desired area ('main'), its content is available for being "tabbed" on.
I have tried adding tabindex="0" on main, but it does not work as expected, because the main also gets a focus, which is not intended. I only want the nested clickable elements to get focus.

Update:
I added a "hack" solution, but I think this is not ideal. Will be happy to learn more about how I can fix this.
    document
      .querySelector("main")
      .addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
        const main = event.target;
        const focusableElement = main.querySelector(
          '[tabindex="0"], button, a, input, select, textarea'
        );

        if (focusableElement) {
          focusableElement.focus();
        }
      });

